# What the diff between @Type and @JdbcType in hibernate 6?

Tags: hibernate

I've upgraded from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1 which uses hibernate 6. It affected syntax of @Type annotations and I don't understand what option I should use:

Old version

```
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
class DbEntity {

   @Type(type = "jsonb")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   var sources: Array<String>? = emptyArray()

}
```

New version option 1

```
@Type(JsonBinaryType::class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
var sources: Array<String>? = emptyArray()
```

New version option 2

```
@JdbcType(JsonJdbcType::class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
var sources: Array<String>? = emptyArray()
```

How knows, please, explain what the difference because I can't find it.